# Gmail label report to spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, gmail

Is there a script i can run in google sheets, which would allow me to report on how many emails.
I have from a label within gmail for a timeframe of say 1 month?
eg: label1 = 50 label 2 = 20 label 3 = 34 etc..
I don't need to know the contents or anything else of the emails just a report on how many.
I have tried to find gmail scripts but i cant find a specific one for this.

Comment: Welcome. Does this help [Reference Gmail labels in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102152/196152)? BTW, though you may say that you don't want to know the content, etc, in order to could the labels you must have full access to the gmail account - this gives you the _ability_ to know the content.

Comment: Please read, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so you can edit your question and in that way it will be easier to help you

Comment: Thanks Tedinoz this did help, however i need to be able to filter the label count by date range for example 1-31st of a month, is this possible?